# Isomorphism including a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I whould like to konw why the following map is an isomorphism :
$ K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f_1,...,f_r) \otimes K [Y_1,...,Y_n]/(g_1,...g_k) 
\simeq K[X_1,...,X_n, Y_1,...,Y_m] / (f_1,...,f_r,g_1,...g_k) $ which $ K $ is an algebraically closed field.
Here is my suggestion :
We put : $ \varphi \ : \ K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f_1,...,f_r) \times K [Y_1,...,Y_n]/(g_1,...g_k) \to K[X_1 , ... , X_n, Y_1 , ... , Y_m ] / (f_1 , ..., f_r , g_1 , ... , g_k) $ défined by : $ \varphi (P,Q) = PQ $ which is bilinear. So, according to the universal property of the tensor product, we obtain the the $ K $ - linear map :
$ f : K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f_1,...,f_r) \otimes K [Y_1,...,Y_n]/(g_1,...g_k) 
\simeq K[X_1,...,X_n, Y_1,...,Y_m] / (f_1,...,f_r,g_1,...g_k) $
so the question : why $ f $ is an isomorphism ? How can we show it. And sorry about my english language, i'm not a british men, sorry.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the kernel is trivial and that a basis of monomials in the codomain are all in $f$'s image.

Comment: Ok! :) $ \forall P \otimes Q \in \ker f $ : $ f ( P \otimes Q ) = 0 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ PQ = 0 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ P = 0 $ or $ Q = 0 $, so $ P \otimes Q = 0 $. So : $ \ker f = \{ 0 \} $. Finally : $ f $ is injective. Can you show me why $ f $ is a surjective map ? I can't do it alone. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The monomials generate the codomain as a vector space. It is simple to see that each monomial is in the image of $f$: just take the very same corresponding monomial, break it up into a product of $X$ and $Y$ monomials, and place it as a tensor in the domain. I.e. $$m(X_i,Y_j)=m_1(X_i)m_2(Y_j)\leftrightarrow m_1(X_i)\otimes m_2(Y_j)$$ ($i,j$ are allowed to vary of course, I am suppressing notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** One way to show that $f$ is an isomorphism is to define it's inverse.  Send $x_i$ to $x_i \otimes 1$ and send $y_i$ to $1 \otimes y_i$.

You'll have to check that this gives a well defined map and that it's the inverse to $f$.

Comment: I don't understand how to choose $ g $ as the inverse of $ f $. Anyhow : $ g : K[X_1,...,X_n, Y_1,...,Y_m]/(f_1,...,f_r,g_1,...g_k) \to K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f_1,...,f_r) \times K [Y_1,...,Y_n]/(g_1,...g_k) $. Do i have to show that $ f \circ g ( x_i ) = \mathrm{id} ( x_i ) $, and $ g (f( x_i \otimes 1 ) ) = \mathrm{id} ( x_i \otimes 1 ) = x_i \otimes 1 $, no ? That all ? Thanks a lot.  :)

Comment: Which family of elements generate $ K[X_1 , ... , X_n , Y_1 , ... , Y_m ] / ( f_1 , ... , f_r , g_1 , ... , g_r ) $ ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not that you choose $g$ to be the inverse of $f$ (because you don't know $f$ has an inverse!).  What you do is you define $g$ as a map and then you check that $gf$ and $fg$ are the identity.  This then proves that the map you defined is the inverse to $f$.  It's basically guess and check, guess what $g$ should be and then check that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Define a map going the other way, and then check that it is an inverse to the one you already have.

Comment: Yes, thank you. :) Is it correct my solution above ?