# Isomorphic of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, tensor-products

I am working on this problem and need a little guidance. I have 2 $k$-algebras $$\frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]}{I} \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{J}$$
where $k$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal of $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and $J$ is an ideal of $k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]$

My goal here is to show that $$\frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]}{I} \otimes_k \frac{k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{J} \cong_k \frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{(I,J)}.$$

My plan is to define a mapping: $$f: \frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]}{I} \times \frac{k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{J} \rightarrow \frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{(I,J)}$$
If I can define a mapping that is bi-additive and k-balanced, then I can use the universal mapping property of tensor products to have a mapping $$\tilde{f} : \frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]}{I} \otimes_k \frac{k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{J} \rightarrow \frac{k[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m]}{(I,J)}.$$ I would still have to make the argument that $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras however.

Can anyone help me in defining $f$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159288/recalling-result-of-tensor-product-of-polynomial-rings) in the definition of $\tilde{f}$ to explicitly define a map?

Edit: This can also be seen as a very nice application of Yoneda's lemma. You can find a related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123543/why-does-a-i-otimes-r-b-j-conga-otimes-r-b-i-otimes-r-11-otimes-r-j)

Comment: I read through both, and though slightly helpful, i still am shaky about what i should explicitly define $f$ to be.

Comment: Would $f(x + I, y + J) = (xy + (I +J))$ work?

Comment: (Sorry about the delayed reply) That was something along the lines of my first guess (except of course, we have more than two variables here). If $g$ and $h$ are in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $k[y_1, \dots, y_m]$ respectively, $f(x_i + I, y_j +J) = x_iy_j + (I+J)$. It is bi-additive and $k-$balanced, so it checks off all the easy boxes. There is still the issue of showing that $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism though.

Comment: (for some reason I can't edit my previous comment), so here is an add on: If $g$ and $h$ are in $k[x_1,…,x_n]$ and $k[y_1,…,y_m]$ respectively, $f(g+I,h+J)=gh+(I+J)$. It is bi-additive and k−balanced, so it checks off the easy boxes. There is the issue of showing that $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism though, I worked through the details, it is messy but doable if you show the isomorphism by constructing an inverse map and showing that composing them gives identity on both ends. Try $\prod_{i,j} x_iy_j \to \prod_i x_i \otimes \prod_j y_j$

Comment: Ill give that a go and see what pops out. Just by a quick inspection though, it should work.

Comment: I did some more hunting, and here's a version of essentially the same exact question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411428/isomorphism-including-a-tensor-product?rq=1 (The inverse map noted in the accepted answer there is more or less the one I suggested above). :D